# How do I reduce the icon size in the Slingshot menu on Loki (0.4)?

Tags: release-loki, slingshot

I have a desktop with 720p resolution. The Slingshot menu takes up 1/2 my screen width and 3/4th of my screen height -- not cool.

How do I reduce the icon size in the Slingshot menu on Loki (0.4), without installing Elementary Tweaks?

This did not work:

`gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.slingshot icon-size 48

killall slingshot-launcher`

The first command gave no error, and the second command said no such process was found. A restart did not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code it looks like Slingshot is now ignoring this value and has the icon size hardcoded into the `src/Widgets/AppEntry.vala` here on [Launchpad](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-pantheon/slingshot/trunk/view/head:/src/Widgets/AppEntry.vala#L100).